# Not use for loop to get previous elements in pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
a   -  b    -   c
0   -  10   -   40  
1   -  20   -   50  
2   -  30   -   60
```

Except for the first row, I'd like to end up with this: (I'm adding each cell value with the one right before it)

```
a   -  b    -   c
0   -  10   -   40  
1   -  30   -   90  
2   -  60   -   150
```

Is this possible without using a for loop?

Comment: likely a `cumsum` ``df.cumsum()``

Comment: `df['c'] = df['c'].cumsum()`